# Using prefix query in eleasticsearch for an integer field

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to use the prefix query to return a list of possible matches. The prefix field is an integer that is not analyzed. I would expect that:

```
{
"prefix": {"id":"1"} 
}
```

Would return all documents where the id starts with 1 (e.g. 1, 10, 11,12,13 etc}. However, it only returns an exact match (e.g. 1).

Does the prefix query work on integer fields?

Answer (score 0):

I'm still learning elasticsearch too, but I believe the field has to be a string. You can work around this by using a multi_field type and adding a string field that you can run your prefix query against. I use the following for a number of fields (integers and non-integers) that I need to run prefix queries against:

Under settings.analysis in your mapping, add:

```
  "analyzer": {
    "str_filtered_search_analyzer": {
      "tokenizer": "keyword",
      "filter": [
        "lowercase"
      ]
    },
    "str_prefix_analyzer": {
      "tokenizer": "keyword",
      "filter": [
        "lowercase",
        "prefix"
      ]
    }
  }
```

And then under mappings.type.properties (replace type with your type e.g. user):

```
  "id": {
    "type": "multi_field",
    "fields": {
      "id": {
        "type": "integer"
      },
      "prefix": {
        "type": "string",                
        "index_analyzer": "str_prefix_analyzer",
        "search_analyzer": "str_filtered_search_analyzer"
      }
    }
  }
```